# Laravel passport client creation using code

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-passport

Does anyone having idea about creating passport client using code as i can be able to create it using commands but how can i achieve it using code ???

Your help is highly appreciate.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it by my own and following is the snippet to generate the oAuth client manually by code.

```
$oauth_client = new oAuthClient();
$oauth_client->user_id =  $last_inserted_id;
$oauth_client->name =  $user->name;
$oauth_client->secret =base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256',Hash::make($_REQUEST['password']), 'secret', true));
$oauth_client->password_client=1;
$oauth_client->personal_access_client   =  0;
$oauth_client->redirect =  'redirect_uri';
$oauth_client->revoked=  0;
$oauth_client->save(); // Saving oauth client
```

Comment: Why use $_REQUEST['password'] when you can use $request->get('password') which is much saver